# how to post parameters in URL without key

Tags: php, .htaccess, server, web

I'm creating a website with PHP. I want to create profile page for my users. I can do this so :

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users.php?uid=5272693&uname=fullofquestion
```

but I want to delete .php extension and parameters key and do it like this :

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/5272693/fullofquestion
```

how can I do this?

Comment: You are talking about URL-rewrite and a rest call , use .htaccess and any rest framework

Comment: You'll want to look into URL Rewriting

Comment: please give me some example code.

Comment: @Satya That isn't specific to rest, any PHP script can use `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`;

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create `.htaccess` file to redirect `users` to `users.php`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?users/(.+)$ users.php [L]
```

Then in `users.php` you can access the `/5272693/fullofquestion` portion of URL with `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`.

Comment: ps. I'm not that good with RewriteRule:s, so if this doesn't work try using path like `.../users.php/5272693/fullofquestion`. If that works but `.../users/...` doesn't then this RewriteRule is wrong. In both cases you can use `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`.

Comment: with this way, I should write a rule for each  url. and user can access the link with .php yet.

Comment: @fullOfQuestion What do you mean "for each url"? What kinds of other URLs you need?

Comment: other pages like home.php. I solved this but how can I perevent accessing .php files?

Comment: @fullOfQuestion Can you use server configuration files instead of `.htaccess`? In there you can use full filesystem path instead of `users.php` and so can use files outside of document root. If not, comments here have some examples, but I don't quite understand how they work: http://php.net/manual/en/security.hiding.php

Answer (score -2):

Create a file named `.htaccess` in your root directory and add these lines :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^users/(.*)/(.*)$ /users.php?uid=$1&uname=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

That should do the trick.